# Angular local scope not available inside observable subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services

I have been struggling with this now for a while and tried many solutions.

Inside my subscribe I cant access ChangeDetectorRef or the NgZone to force an update on my scope.

Why doesn't anything work? Is there any other Angular aware way of doing HTTP requests?

**The login component**

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
    providers: [LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    zone: NgZone;
    username = '';
    password = '';
    showerror = false;
    errormsg = '';
    rs = {};
    results: any;


    constructor(private _loginService: LoginService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

    }

    refr = function () {
        console.log('refresh');
        console.log(this.errormsg); // is empty even after HTTP call
        this.ref.markForCheck();
        console.log(this.results);
    };

    login = function () {
        console.log(this.username, this.password);

        this._loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(function (data) {

            console.log('log me in');
            console.log(data); // the correct data is logged here
            this.errormsg = 'Invalid Username and Password'; // the text is never updated
            this.zone.run(); // zone has no method run
            this.ref.markForCheck(); // ref has no method markForCheck
        });

        // this.results = this._loginService.login(this.username, this.password);
        // this.results.subscribe(rs => this.rs = rs);   
    };

    ngOnInit() {

    }

}
```

**The login service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CONFIG} from '../config';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

const loginUrl: string = CONFIG.apiserv + 'api.login.php';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    private http;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    login = function (username, password): Observable<Response> {
        console.log('login clicked');
        let url = new URLSearchParams();
        url.append('username', username);
        url.append('password', password);
        const fullurl = loginUrl + '?' + url.toString();

        return this.http.get(fullurl)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    };
    handleError = function (error: Response) {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you are using `this`, you should use `arrow function`:

```
this._loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {

        console.log('log me in');
        console.log(data); // the correct data is logged here
        this.errormsg = 'Invalid Username and Password'; // the text is never updated
        this.zone.run(); 
        this.ref.markForCheck(); 
    });
```

Comment: beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bind `this` to a newly crated scope you need to use `=>`.

```
this._loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(data => {
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Otherwise, you could assign the `this` to a variable but it's not necessary if you're using TypeScript or ES6.

```
var that = this;
this._loginService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(function (data) {
    that.zone.run();
    ...
```